# Referencing Assemblies when executing U-SQL Application scripts against local-project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, assemblies, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a U-SQL DB Project (`USQLdb`) that defines a U-SQL database and it's constituent tables, procedues, etc.  This project also references two assemblies for use in one of the stored procedures.  The DLL files are held within a folder called `assemblies` within the U-SQL Data Root folder and are referenced within the database using the following script:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]
FROM "/assemblies/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.0.0.0.0/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";
```

This works when deploying to `Local-machine` or to Azure.

For testing purposes, I have added a U-SQL Application Project (`USQLScripts`) that references `USQLdb`, with U-SQL scripts that execute a stored procedure each with the aim of setting up Unit Testing.

When trying to run these scripts against `Local-project: USQLdb` however, database deployment fails.  From the logs it is because the `USQLdb` deployment script cannot find the referenced assemblies in the `Local-project` data root folder:

`*** Error : (204,6) 'Assembly file 'C:\<Solution Folder>\USQLScripts\bin\Debug\DataRoot\assemblies/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.0.0.0.0/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll' could not be read.'`

I have specified the `USQLScripts` `Test Data Source` as the local U-SQL Data Root folder which copies all files found to the `Local-project` working directory here:

```
C:\<Solution Folder>\USQLScripts\bin\Debug\USQLScripts_altdata_5qktnwfj.gln\data'
```

though per the error message above, the `USQLdb` Assembly Reference is trying to find them here:

```
C:\<Solution Folder>\USQLScripts\bin\Debug\DataRoot
```

As the `DataRoot` folder is completely cleaned and recreated on each `Local-project` execution, how can I either get the assemblies into the `DataRoot` folder on execution or reference them approriately without changing the address in the U-SQL script included earlier, which works as required when deployed to Azure?

---

Turns out, that if I remove the U-SQL Database reference in `USQLScripts`, the files that are in the `Test Data Source` folder are now copied to the `C:\<Solution Folder>\USQLScripts\bin\Debug\DataRoot` folder, but the scripts cannot execute as the database they are trying to execute against hasn't been referenced.  I get the impression that I am either missing something or have hit a bug/unintended behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing something.

What I thought was an error in referencing the assemblies was actually an error in building the `USQLdb` project, that resulted in the assemblies not being available and a red herring of an error being thrown.

The culprit was the `Target Framework Version` of the assemblies being higher than both the `USQLdb` and `USQLScripts` projects.  It appears this can only be changed by editing the `.usqldbproj` files manually in a text editor (specifically the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` value), as there is no option within the Visual Studio UI to edit this project property that I can find.

Once I upped the `Target Framework Version` in the U-SQL projects to match those of the assemblies, everything now builds, deploys and executes as expected.